# I am unable to install module for my Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I am a newbie to Drupal and was trying to develop a website. I am in need of modules to enhance and when trying to install them , it throws the following error.

> Warning: ftp_login(): Login incorrect. in FileTransferFTPExtension->connect() (line 59 of ..)
>   Check Username and Password

My username and password are perfect. Can someone please help??

Comment: Are you trying to do that on a local computer, or on a remote server? Are you sure you are entering the credentials for the FTP server, and not the credentials for your Drupal account?

Answer (score 3):

The alternate way to install module is to download the module and untar/unzip the files under **/drupal/sites/all/modules/**

Using Admin UI you can enable the module.